# Memory limit issue with screen casting using the broadcast extension and WebRTC protocol on iOS

Tags: ios, webrtc

This is my first question posted on stackoverflow.

I'm trying to make screen cast app using BroadcastExtension and WebRTC protocol. But broadcast extension's memory limit(50mb) is so tight that if an application tries to send the original video(886 x 1918 30fps) without any processing, it immediately dies after receiving a memory usage warning. After lowering the resolution and frame rate of the video, there is no problem. Investigating the application using the profiler does not seem to cause any problems with memory leaks. I guess it is because of the frames allocated during the encoding process inside WebRTC framework.

So my question is, is it possible to send the original video using WebRTC without any other processing, such as down scaling or lowering the frame rate?

Answer (score 0):

Possible.

I forgot to mention in the question, but the library I used is Google WebRTC. I made two mistakes. One is to build the modified framework in debug mode, and the other is to use a software encoder(default is VP8). Because of this, it seems that the processing of the video frames was delayed and accumulated in the memory. DefaultEncoderFactory basically provides an encoder that operates in SW. (At least on iOS. Android seems to support HW-based decoder encoders automatically.) Fortunately, the iOS version google WebRTC framework supports the H264 hardware encoder(EncoderFactoryH264). In other cases you have to implement it yourself.

However, when using H264 to transmit, there is a problem that some platforms cannot play, for example, Android. The Google webrtc group seems to be aware of this problem, but at least it seems to me that it has not been resolved properly. Additional work is needed to solve this.